# Google cloud messaging custom permissiom

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-permissions

I am new in GCM and face problem when I declared permission in manifest file.
When I run app it gives me IllegalStateException Application does not define permission `com.example.technopits.dcn.permission.C2D_MESSAGE`
so please help me.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.technopits.dcn" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <!-- Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages. -->
    <permission
        android:name="com.example.technopits.dcn.GCM.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.technopits.dcn.GCM.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <!-- Network State Permissions to detect Internet status -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <!-- Permission to vibrate -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme.Base" >
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>

                <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.example.technopits.dcn" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>



        <activity android:name=".activity.Test"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.MultiLogin"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".GCM.Main"></activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

I get permission error in logcat

```
10-16 19:46:47.265    7663-7663/com.example.technopits.dcn E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.technopits.dcn, PID: 7663
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.technopits.dcn/com.example.technopits.dcn.GCM.Main}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application does not define permission com.example.technopits.dcn.permission.C2D_MESSAGE
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application does not define permission com.example.technopits.dcn.permission.C2D_MESSAGE
            at com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(GCMRegistrar.java:123)
            at com.example.technopits.dcn.GCM.Main.onCreate(Main.java:69)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I am using android studio 1.3.2

Answer (score 0):

You have a permission

```
com.example.technopits.dcn.GCM.permission.C2D_MESSAGE
```

It is asking for

```
com.example.technopits.dcn.permission.C2D_MESSAG
```

Remove the `.GCM` part of your permissions so that it matches the requested permission format.